# Passing non generic objects into a generic collection

Tags: c#

I have a set of rules which is defined by this interface:

```
public interface IRule<in T>
    {
        bool IsBroken(T dataObject);
    }
```

Sample implementations:

```
class Rule1:IRule<DateTime>
    {
        public bool IsBroken(DateTime dataObject)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

class Rule2:IRule<int>
{
    public bool IsBroken(int dataObject)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have another class which passess back the lsit of rules as below:

```
class RulesCollection
    {
        public IEnumerable<IRule<what>> GetAllRules()
        {
            yield return new Rule1();
            yield return new Rule2();
        }
    }
```

The issue 'am facing here is- how will pass back the rule1 & rule2 into `IEnumerable<IRule<T>>`, since T is going to be different for various rules it does't allow me to do so. Is there a way to get over this issue?

Using .NET 4.

Comment: How can clients use the returned rules if they don't know the type of the argument to supply to `IsBroken`?

Comment: It is not possible, generics are different types even though they share code. Think of it as if you wanted to return ints and strings from your method, that won't work. Maybe if you explain what you need to do with the result of your method `GetAllRules` we could help you find something to help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the meaning of the return value of `IsBroken`, you could do something like:

```
public class RuleWrapper<T> : IRule<object>
{
    private readonly IRule<T> inner;
    public RuleWrapper(IRule<T> inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public bool IsBroken(object obj)
    {
        return obj is T && this.inner.IsBroken((T)obj);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public IEnumerable<IRule<object>> GetAllRules()
{
    yield return new RuleWrapper<DateTime>(new Rule1());
    yield return new RuleWrapper<int>(new Rule2());
}
```

Comment: Of course now you're removing static type checking, effectively defeating the purpose of using generics in the first place.